# Fundamental theorem of $\Gamma$-convergence

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, pointwise-convergence

In the [paper](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Ebraides/Handbook.pdf) "A handbook of Γ-convergence" I've read the following:

"This is the fundamental theorem of Γ-convergence, that is summarized by the implication
Γ-convergence + equicoerciveness $\implies$ convergence of minimum problems".

My question is -
if we want to construct a sequence of the functionals which has (the limits are exist) a $\Gamma$-limit and a pointwise limit but they're not equal, then can we take a sequence which is not equicoercive?